# Не загружается кнопка при использовании Selenium WebDriver (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь просмотреть каталог по адресу: https://lenta.com/catalog/frukty-i-ovoshchi/.

Отображаются только первые 24 элемента, чтобы увидеть больше нужно нажать на кнопку "Загрузить еще" внизу страницы.

Проблема в том, что при использовании Selenium кнопка на странице не появляется - как будто в каталоге всего 24 элемента.
Я вручную пролистывал вниз окно марионетки - кнопки там нет.
Если просто зайти на сайт через Firefox - кнопка есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста - что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as WDW

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://lenta.com/catalog/frukty-i-ovoshchi/')
wait = WDW(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_class_name('button--primary catalog-grid-container__pagination-buttonr')))
```

Comment: У меня по вашей ссылке в обычном хроме (без аддонов) тоже нет ни какой кнопки

Comment: Обратите внимание вверху на строку адреса магазина из которого показаны товары. Лента может разные магазины вам показывать